# TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly while working with sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, byte, recv

So I'm trying to convert code from Python 2.7 to Python 3, and it seems as though something has changed. I'm trying to receive binary data over a socket and now it doesn't work. Here's my code.

EDIT: I have added my send code. Also, I don't really like the way it works right now, it's overcomplicated. If you can it would be nice to have a better way of sending/receiving data.

```
def recv(self):
    # Receive the length of the incoming message (unpack the binary data)
    dataLength = socket.ntohl(struct.unpack("I", self._recv(4))[0])

    # Receive the actual data
    return self._recv(dataLength)

def _recv(self, length):
    try:
        data = ''
        recvLen = 0
        while recvLen < length:
            newData = self.sock.recv(length-recvLen)

            if newData == '':
                self.isConnected = False
                raise exceptions.NetworkError(errors.CLOSE_CONNECTION, errno=errors.ERR_CLOSED_CONNECTION)

            data = data + newData # TypeError here
            recvLen += len(newData)

        return data
    except socket.error as se:
        raise exceptions.NetworkError(str(se))

def send(self, data):
    if type(data) is not str:
        raise TypeError()

    dataLength = len(data)

    # Send the length of the message (int converted to network byte order and packed as binary data)
    self._send(struct.pack("I", socket.htonl(dataLength)), 4)

    # Send the actual data
    self._send(data, dataLength)

def _send(self, data, length):
    sentLen = 0
    while sentLen < length:
        try:
            amountSent = self.sock.send(data[sentLen:])
        except Exception:
            self.isConnected = False
            raise exceptions.NetworkError(errors.UNEXPECTED_CLOSE_CONNECTION)

        if amountSent == 0:
            self.isConnected = False
            raise exceptions.NetworkError(errors.UNEXPECTED_CLOSE_CONNECTION)

        sentLen += amountSent
```

Comment: always put **FULL** error message in **QUESTION**. There are other usefull information, ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: You probably want to read through http://python3porting.com/problems.html#bytes-strings-and-unicode

Comment: @furas The question contains all the information required, if you look at the code I put a comment where the exact error happens. The error message is in the title. What else would you be looking for?

Comment: @Amber I'll check it out although it hasn't helped me before

Comment: don't expect that we will read all your code. And error message has many other usefull information which can be usefull for us.

Comment: @furas There isn't that much code, most people on here have their entire class but I only have two not that big functions.

Comment: every day we check hundreds of questions and watch thousands of lines of code - so every information can be useful and helps resolve problem.

Comment: @ken596 I have found this link (with a similar problem to what you are facing): https://www.mkyong.com/python/python-3-typeerror-cant-convert-bytes-object-to-str-implicitly/ very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 3 sends data as bytes so you have to decode to string

```
 data = data + newData.decode('utf-8')

 # or 

 data = data + newData.decode('ascii')
```

if you need bytes data then use

```
 data = b''
```

and keep without `.decode()`

```
 data = data + newData
```

---

**EDIT:** for new code in question.

When you send you have to convert/encode string to bytes and after that get its length. Native chars has length 1 as unicode but they can use 2 bytes (or more).

When you receive you have to work with bytes `b''` and at the end convert/decode bytes to string again.

See comments `# <--` in code

```
def send(self, data):
    if not isinstance(data, str): # <-- prefered method
    #if type(data) is not str:
        raise TypeError()

    data = data.encode('utf-8') # <-- convert to bytes

    # get size of bytes
    dataLength = len(data)

    # Send the length of the message (int converted to network byte order and packed as binary data)
    self._send(struct.pack("I", socket.htonl(dataLength)), 4)

    # Send the actual data
    self._send(data, dataLength)


def recv(self):
    # Receive the length of the incoming message (unpack the binary data)
    dataLength = socket.ntohl(struct.unpack("I", self._recv(4))[0])

    # Receive the actual data
    return self._recv(dataLength).decode('utf-8') # <-- convert to string again

def _recv(self, length):
    try:
        data = b'' # <-- use bytes
        recvLen = 0
        while recvLen < length:
            newData = self.sock.recv(length-recvLen)

            #if newData == b'': # <-- use bytes
            if not newData:    # <-- or 
                self.isConnected = False
                raise exceptions.NetworkError(errors.CLOSE_CONNECTION, errno=errors.ERR_CLOSED_CONNECTION)

            data = data + newData # TypeError here
            recvLen += len(newData)

        return data
    except socket.error as se:
        raise exceptions.NetworkError(str(se))
```